# Software to manage classes/courses

Tags: project-management

I'm looking for software or a web-application to manage courses. My business sells all kinds of classes to companies and manages everything for those companies.

As of now we work with Excel sheets to keep track of the participants, the trainer, costs & income, who paid and who hasn't, etc. etc. Those are features I'd like to see in the software.

In case of software it should run on Windows. We are a small company so we cannot afford too expensive licenses. We used MS Dynamics in the past which was about about 200 euro a month. We'd prefer a cheaper solution.

Are there more specified solutions to manage these kind of projects?

Answer (score 2):

So a list of your requirements:

- desktop (windows) or web-based;
- Participants/students/enrolled tracking;
- Trainer/Lecturer/Teacher;
- Manage Finance;
- Manage Lectures/Courses and also content;

For the complete package, I would suggest Moodle. It is a comprehensive tool for learning. From my view it is more focused for teaching institutions, but would also be great for smaller companies and teachers/consultants.

Another application which I believe may also help would be Forma.LMS. It is a platform like Moodle. There is also Chamilo, however I am not sure there is an english version of the software (the website is all in spanish). Of the above I have only used Moodle, and that was very basic use - end user and not institution or school - so I am not aware of any financial management on its part, but since it is also online learning platform, it should have some integration with cost tracking/enrollment management.

Links: https://www.formalms.org/

https://moodle.org/

https://www.chamilo.org/

The above, are basically focused on the "learning" aspect, where you can manage also online courses, however, maybe what you are looking for is something more of a "e-commerce" situation, where you have a product and would like to manage the sales. I would suggest to take a look at Magento. It is a flexible e-commerce platform. I have not used it, however it may be able to incorporate your requirements.

Link: https://magento.com/

All of these are hosted web based solutions, since I think it would be best to have an integrated option. I have searched without success for a windows option, however I did find something on the Mac side: iTeacherBook. It is focused on courses, content and teaching, not the financial aspects, and it is Mac but maybe it can be a starting point for finding a windows counterpart.

Link: http://iteacherbook.com/

In any case I hope this helped in finding the proper solution for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Web-based is not bad since we need multiple users to work in the same database and I have no problem with running a websever. I will surely look into your recommendations!